# Why won't my object serialize?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, datacontractserializer, ixmlserializable

I have a class. It implements IXmlSerializable. I can't get Web API 2 to serialize it.

Here is my class:

```
public class MyType: IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // some code
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is the response:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
        The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace />
    <InnerException>
        <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
        <ExceptionMessage>Type 'MyType' with data contract name 'XmlConverter:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNamespace' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.</ExceptionMessage>
        <ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</ExceptionType>
        <StackTrace>
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
            at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.&lt;WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync&gt;d__1b.MoveNext()
        </StackTrace>
    </InnerException>
</Error>
```

I've tried `[DataContract]`. That changes the 'Type 'MyNamespace.MyType' cannot be IXmlSerializable and have DataContractAttribute attribute.' I've tried using `[XmlSchemaProvider("Method", IsAny = true)]`, with `Method` returning null, which gives me the original error again. `DataContractSerializer` is supposed to be able to serialize `IXmlSerializables`. What gives?

P.S.: WriteXml is not being called at all.

Comment: Probably because `MyType` is a subclass of some polymorphic type and you did not declare it in the [list of known types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  What is the context in which `MyType` is being serialized?  If it's not the root object (and it probably isn't), how is it being referenced?

Comment: I have no idea anymore. I think I went a completely different route and wrote my own interface and serializer that delegates to an xml writer or json.net. I doubt the class in question exists any more.

Comment: So, close it off then as not reproducible?